# Calculate the values of all fields of a tables, called rooms. Tried to pluck the data in a nested array,sum the inner arrays in the nested array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to calculate the total rooms

This is the schema

```
create_table "rooms", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "single_bedroom_num"
    t.integer "double_bedroom_num"
    t.integer "suite_room_num"
    t.integer "dormitory_room_num"
    t.bigint "hotel_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["hotel_id"], name: "index_rooms_on_hotel_id"
  end
```

I want to add the values submitted in the form as total_rooms_available.
My Room table currently has these values

```
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Room id: 2, single_bedroom_num: 2, double_bedroom_num: 5, suite_room_num: 1, dormitory_room_num: 3, hotel_id: 3, created_at: "2019-12-08 09:30:45", updated_at: "2019-12-08 09:30:45">, #<Room id: 3, single_bedroom_num: 2, double_bedroom_num: 1, suite_room_num: 4, dormitory_room_num: 3, hotel_id: 4, created_at: "2019-12-10 07:52:10", updated_at: "2019-12-10 07:52:10">]>
```

```
array = Room.pluck(:single_bedroom_num, :double_bedroom_num, :suite_room_num, :dormitory_room_num)
# (0.7ms)  SELECT `rooms`.`single_bedroom_num`, `rooms`.`double_bedroom_num`, `rooms`.`suite_room_num`, `rooms`.`dormitory_room_num` FROM `rooms`
# => [[2, 5, 1, 3], [2, 1, 4, 3]]
```

I want to add [2+5+1+3] = 11and also [2+1+4+3] =10 so that i know the total rooms are [11,10]

Comment: There is a picture link of the rails console in "How can.."

Comment: Try to create an elaborated and detailed question. Otherwise not many people will take the time even on clicking to open your image.

Comment: Readers should be able to get all the details needed to help you in your question, without having to change the browser tab.

Comment: okay, doing that, thank you.

Comment: You can update your own question. Don't add comments with parts of the question.

Comment: okay i did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the output of `pluck`, this way you can pass a string using the `SUM` function of your RDBMS.

Try with:

```
Room.group(:id).pluck('SUM(single_bedroom_num + double_bedroom_num + suite_room_num + dormitory_room_num)')
```

Comment: this is leading to a output 21,(11+10). I wanted 11, 10 seperately

Comment: Yes, my bad. You need to group first.

Comment: i tried doing, i m new here i dont have 15 reputation so they are not accepting it. But once i have i will surely.